# Is it possible to sync to two computers with Zune without the device being a guest on one of them?

Tags: sync, zune

In the days of Windows Sync Center, it was possible to associate a device with at least 2 PCs, because I guess people would plug them in at work and home.

With Zune, I can create a Sync relationship between my device and 1 computer, and then connect as a "Guest" device on other machines.

Is it possible to create a Sync relationship on both my work and home machines? If I change the relationship at work from "Guest", will that break the relationship with my home PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phone can only have primary sync relationship with once computer. If you were to change the relationship on your work computer your home computer will become the guest.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can still pull content off, even when it is connected as a guest.